# Remove text at specific coordinates from PDF with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

Can somebody help my with this issue? I have coordinates which includes x1, x2, y1, y2, page and what I need is replace this text with black rectangle (this is not problem), but I need also remove text under this rectangle to protect.

I can't find any delete method. My idea was find words in this area (done) and replace them to empty string, but PDFBox no longer support replace.

One solution for this what I found is iText, but I'm limited to pdfBox.

Any ideas?

Comment: *"One solution for this what I found is iText"* - itext does not offer direct text replacement. It has an actual redaction tool which is something completely different.